# How to configure an AWS CodeBuild buildspec to use a dynamic ReportGroup created by CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codebuild

AWS have recently (20/12/19) released support for [shared CodeBuild Report Groups in CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-codebuild-reportgroup.html)

I'd like to use a [ReportGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/test-reporting.html) in my CloudFormation, but can't see how I'm supposed to configure CodeBuild to use it.

It looks like reporting configuration is done in the buildspec. I can see an example of a hardcoded reference to a report group in [this example buildspec snippet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/report-group-test-cases.html):

```
reports:
  arn:aws:codebuild:your-region:your-aws-account-id:report-group/report-group-name-1: #surefire junit reports
    files:
      - '**/*'
    base-directory: 'surefire/target/surefire-reports'
    discard-paths: false
```

Obviously, if I'm creating my ReportGroup via CloudFormation, I don't know the ARN to put into the buildspec.

So, my question is how can I inject a dynamically created report group ARN into the buildspec? Or is there a different/better way of configuring CodeBuild to use a ReportGroup created by CloudFormation?

Answer (score 4):

If it is all being created by CloudFormation then you could add the buildspec.yaml creation to the template and add the ARN via the [intrinsic function Fn::Sub or !Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html)

```
  CodeBuildProject:
    Type: "AWS::CodeBuild::Project"
    Properties:
      Source:
        Type: NO_SOURCE
        BuildSpec: !Sub |
          version: 0.2
          env:
            variables:
              key: "value"
              key: "value"
          phases:
            install:
              runtime-versions:
                runtime: version
              commands:
                - command
            pre_build:
              commands:
                - command
            build:
              commands:
                - command
            post_build:
              commands:
                - command
          reports:
            arn:aws:codebuild:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccontID}:report-group/${ReportGroupName}:
              files:
                - location
              base-directory: location
              discard-paths: yes
              file-format: JunitXml | CucumberJson
```

Take note of the **!Sub** after BuildSpec.

Where *ReportGroupName* is equal to the name property value given in *AWS::CodeBuild::ReportGroup*

Comment: Thanks, can you include an example of how you would use that in the buildspec YAML?

Comment: The ENV VAR solution wouldn't work because the ARN is a property and cannot be replaced. I have modified my answer to fix this.

Comment: Seems like source type is required.

Comment: Thanks for the catch @Mark I have amended the answer.